# html5 data attribute show in text

Tags: javascript, html

I found a sample program in w3school about data attribute, and I want to customize the display in paragraph form than in alert box and display it under list clicked.

how can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showDetails(animal) {
    var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
    alert("The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Species</h1>
<p>Click on a species to see what type it is:</p>

<ul>
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="owl" data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
   <!--show here-->
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="salmon" data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
  <!--show here-->  
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="tarantula" data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>  
  <!--show here-->
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.insertAdjacentHTML` with parameter `afterend` , substituting placing string within `<p></p>` for placing string within `alert()` , adding `animal.onclick = null` at close of `showDetails` to call `showDetails` at most once

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function showDetails(animal) {
      var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
      animal
      .insertAdjacentHTML("afterend"
        , "<p>The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".</p>");
      animal.onclick = null;          
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Species</h1>
  <p>Click on a species to see what type it is:</p>

  <ul>
    <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="owl" data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
    <!--show here-->
    <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="salmon" data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
    <!--show here-->
    <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="tarantula" data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
    <!--show here-->
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is the output I expect but the problem is when it click again it add another paragraph

Comment: @misdirection See updated post. Added `animal.onclick = null` at close of `showDetails`

Answer (score 1):

Create a `<p>` designated as an output element (or, if you're into semantics, you could use `<output>`). Then, select it by its id, and set its `innerHTML` to the proper output:

```js
// Select the <p> tag by its id attribute
var outputElement = document.getElementById("output");

function showDetails(animal) {
  var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
  // Instead of an alert()
  outputElement.innerHTML = ("The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".");
}
```

```html
<h1>Species</h1>
<p>Click on a species to see what type it is:</p>

<ul>
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="owl" data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
  <!--show here-->
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="salmon" data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
  <!--show here-->
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="tarantula" data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
  <!--show here-->
</ul>

<!-- Output element with the id of "output" -->
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Sir thanks for the answer I appreciate it, but it didn't show below in every list item

Comment: @misdirection My apologies. I thought "...display it under list clicked." was referring to the list, not each list item. Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry sir my mistake

Answer (score 0):

First, put your `<script>` tags before the end of `</body>` and add the following code:

```
<script>
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p'); // create new <p> element
    document.body.appendChild(paragraph); // add it to your <body> tag
function showDetails(animal) {
    var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
    paragraph.innerHTML = "The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".";
}
```